# SonarQube Dashboard - Can I show just the leaks

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using the latest version of SonarQube.  Is it possible to display the front "Projects" dashboard with just covering the leaks period?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in SonarQube 6.3, but it will be implemented in SonarQube 6.4 for sure.

You can watch the ticket [SONAR-8912](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8912) that we'll soon start working on.